# ArchUnit allow limited number of violations for ratcheting

Tags: java, archunit

I am currently thinking about using archunit for a project.
The project has grown over many years and now I would face a lot of violations if I would proceed.

Is there a way to make a rue not fail if the number of violations is below a certain threshold?

Something like

```
private static final ArchRule limit_something = classes().should([...]).failThreshold(10);
```

This would prevent new code from doing unwanted things and allow me to fix this without a big bang change.

Edit: I do not want to have extra setup for a Freeze-Store.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [freeze the existing violations](https://www.archunit.org/userguide/html/000_Index.html#_freezing_arch_rules) and have only new violations reported.

> By default `FreezingArchRule` will use a simple `ViolationStore` based on plain text files. This is sufficient to add these files to any version control system to continuously track the progress.

For more details, please have a look at the user guide.

Comment: I was aware of the freezing when writing this question but I thought it was needed to set up some external store. Turns out you can have a plaintext store checked in with your repo. This low setup is what I was searching for. Would you mind updating your answer to point this out?

Comment: I usually prefer to link information rather than duplicating it, as the redundant copy can get outdated, but well, if it helps the users... ‍♂️